# Azure AD B2C: Persisting a default value for a claim during local sign up

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

In my application I'm trying to use a custom user attribute, `extension_Role`, that should be persisted to the user during sign up.

I'd like one class of user, say "Customer" to sign-up via a mobile application and not need to provide the Role field, just default it to "Customer" behind the scenes. A second class of user will sign-up using a web app, and I'd like them to be able to select the role from a drop-down, say "Support", "Admin", etc... My plan is to provide two versions of `SignUpOrSignin.xml` to handle this.

Using the sample policy files Microsoft provide in the [starter pack](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-custom-policy-starterpack) I've defined my custom `ClaimType` (with no `UserInputType`) in `TrustFrameworkBase.xml` and configured the client and object IDs. I've also modified the `AAD-UserWriteUsingLogonEmail` `TechnicalProfile` to persist the claim.

I'm stuck with actually persisting a default value. I've tried adding:

```
<OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="extension_Role" AlwaysUseDefaultValue="true" DefaultValue="Customer" />
```

to `SignUpOrSignin.xml`, however when I run the flow, I get a 500 error once I click on sign up. I think this is because it is expecting that the `extension_Role` field should be filled in by the user.

The only way I've been able to persist `extension_Role` is by adding it to the `LocalAccountSignUpWithLogonEmail` `TechnicalProfile` in `TrustFrameworkBase.xml`. For example:

```
<OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="extension_Role" DefaultValue="Customer"/>
```

However since this in the base file, it is shared by all login flows, which would prevent me from setting different values for different sign up flows.

What is the correct way to model this kind of dual sign-up flow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must specify the `UserInputType` when you collect information from the user by using a self-asserted technical profile. See reference [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/bs-latn-ba/azure/active-directory-b2c/claimsschema#userinputtype). It is why you get 500 error.

Please note that the Claim you set in `SignUpOrSignin.xml` (with `<OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="extension_Role" AlwaysUseDefaultValue="true" DefaultValue="Customer" />`) will be only returned after your sign-up at that time. The custom attribute won't be stored into Azure AD. That means when you want to query the custom attribute later, you won't find it.

So you have to set the value of `extension_Role` in Base policy file rather than `SignUpOrSignin.xml`.

In this scene, you should define two TechnicalProfiles for `LocalAccountSignUpWithLogonEmail` and one accepts user input, and the other one sets DefaultValue for your custom claim.

Then reference them separately from your two `SignUpOrSignin.xml`.

Comment: The point is that I don't want to accept input from the user in all cases. In one flow, I want the value to be defaulted and I don't want the user to be able to input it. And in the other flow, I'd like the user to input the value.

Comment: @Tim Yes. I totally undderstand the scene you described. As I have suggested in my answer, you need to reference the TechnicalProfiles for `LocalAccountSignUpWithLogonEmail` from your `SignUpOrSignin.xml`. Now that you have two versions of `SignUpOrSignin.xml`, you can also have two versions of TechnicalProfiles for `LocalAccountSignUpWithLogonEmail` in the Base policy file. One accepts user input, and the other one sets DefaultValue for your custom claim.